# mypy error: Incompatible return value type (got "object", expected "Dict[Any, Any]")

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python class that looks as following:

```
class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, input_data):
        self.input_data = input_data #always 'a' or 'b'

    def test(self) -> dict[int, Any]:
        a = {'a': {1:0, 2:0}, 'b': {2:0, 3:'string'}}
        return a[self.input_data]
```

running mypy results in the error message `Incompatible return value type (got "object", expected "Dict[Any, Any]")`. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I also get the same problem with one line if statements, e.g. if I return a different integer depending on a condition and annotate the return type as int, an error message is raised that "object" type is returned.

Comment: If `input_data` must always be `"a"` or `"b"` you should add that typing information. And `dict[str, Any]` isn't the right return type for `test` because `a[self.input_data]` is always going to be a dictionary whose key is `int`, not `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a type annotation to `a`:

```py
a: dict[str, Any] = {'a': {1:0, 2:0}, 'b': {2:0, 3:'string'}}
```

It seems like this function is returning a `dict[int, Any]`, not a `dict[str, Any]`, but I'm not sure what you intend.

Edit: from your edit it seems that you do want `dict[int, Any]`. In that case, you can narrow `a`’s type to `dict[str, dict[int, Any]]`.